# Require() works on localhost without parens but gives error in production

Tags: php, localhost, require, production, parentheses

I have the code below, well a section of it that works perfectly on localhost

```php
<?php
require "core.php";
class Messenger
{
    private $phone;
    private $message;
```

I have omitted the rest of the code as it is of no importance here.
So this code works well when on localhost but when I upload it to a subdomain like demo.example.com, it gives the error below.

> **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"core.php"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)**

What could be the issue?